# Resample sprite while scaling down in Cocos2D

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I am trying to scale down a high resolution CCSprite in Cocos2D by setting the scale of the sprite as such:

```
mySprite.scale = 0.5f;
```

The problem is that the scaled-down image is not resampled, and appears pixelated.
Is there a way to get a resampled version of the sprite in Cocos2D, or enable resampling at some level in the Cocos2D hierarchy (CCLayer, CCScene, CCDirector, etc.)?

Comment: this won't give good quality or good performance. Are you trying to avoid including SD images?

Comment: No, I just want to implement zoom-in/zoom-out for a large map. Performance is not an issue, since not much is going on anyway other than viewing the map, and there will be a discrete number of zoom levels instead of being continuous.

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting:

```
[texture setAliasTexParameters];
```

on the sprite texture and see if that improve things.

Otherwise, the only approach that I see is resampling the image at the OpenGl level. This would involve using [`gluScaleImage`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/gluScaleImage.xml) on your texture and would be slightly more complex to attain.

Comment: Thanks sergio! I have tried setAliasTexParameters and it didn't do the trick. I will give gluScaleImage a try.

Comment: As a note, I have also tried setAntiAliasTexParameters and that didn't work either.